# Dotnet Core Azure Function (Isolated process) how to load appsettings.json per environment

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to find a way to load environment based `appsettings.json` file into Azure Function.

When working locally the `local.settings.json` is been loaded by default. However, if I want to deploy into other environment per say `STAGING` I would want to load `staging.settings.json`. I went though the Azure Function documentation and found that I need to set `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT` variable (Mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azure_functions_environment).

Once I will set this environment how do I actually go about loading the `staging.settings.json` in the code?

I am using Azure Function Version 3 with dotnet core.

Here is my current unfinished sample

```
 public static async Task Main()
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostBuilder, configuration) =>
                {
                      // Do I Load Json File per environment here? 
                })
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults((hostBuilder, worker) =>
                {
                    //Will be regestering custom middleware here 
                }) //configure middleware here
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) => // configure services for DI
                {
                    services.RegisterLogger();
                  

                })
                .Build();

            await host.RunAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load a `json` file inside your `ConfigureAppConfiguration()` block like this:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

        var config = builder.Build();
    };
```

However, if you are deploying to the Azure function, they have their own Configuration sections where you can specify your settings and set them to be slot specific (meaning you can have different settings for Staging and Production). In that case, all you will want to do is add this to the builder and it should pull in the settings from that Configuration page:

`builder.AddEnvironmentVariables()`

So you will end up with something like this:

```
builder
.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

This will then work locally with dev and in Azure. You should avoid copying these json files and opt for using something like Azure App Configuration if you can, as this will make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am aware that I can add `builder.AddEnvironmentVariables()` . In your example with `ConfigureAppConfiguration` how can I add using something like this `builder.AddJsonFile($"{myEnvVariable}.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);` where `myEnvVariable` will be something like `qa`, so the result will be `qa.settings.json`. The problem is how do I pull that Env variable on Func that is gets passed in `ConfigureAppConfiguration`. @Damo

Answer (score -1):

As per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environment-based-startup-class-and-methods) you can change the Env values in your Start Up class

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _env = env;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_env.EnvironmentName);
        }
        else if (_env.IsStaging())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_env.EnvironmentName);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not dev or staging");
        }

        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I load custom json files bases on environment into Azure function? Example you provided is for API projects. I understand how API projects merge json files based on environment variable and named convention on json files. I am trying to do same in azure function.